# set select option back to default selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the select option back to the "choices" every time I finish adding a new row. How can I do it here? Please help. Btw, adding new row(s) works just fine. Here is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#Add-btn').live('click',function() {
      $("#tabName tr:last").before("<tr><td class='greyed'><input type='hidden' name='allele' value='" + a + "'>" + a + "</td><td><input type='button' class='delete' value='Remove'></td></tr>");
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tabName">
...
<select size='1' id="a" name='a'>
   <option value="None" selected>choices</option>
   <option value='1'>first</option>
   <option value='2'>second</option>
</select>
...
</table>
<div>
   <input id="Add-btn" class="button" type="button" value="Add" />
   <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it back by using [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value, like this:

```
$("#a").val('None');
```

Overall it'll look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Add-btn').live('click',function() {
    $("#tabName tr:last").before("<tr><td class='greyed'><input type='hidden' name='allele' value='" + a + "'>" + a + "</td><td><input type='button' class='delete' value='Remove'></td></tr>");
    $("#a").val('None');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic approach that will allow for you to reset a number of values:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var DefaultValuesElements=$(":input").not("#resetvalues");  // The elements you want to reset (in this example, all input values, except for the button with the ID resetvalues

  function getDefaultValues() {
    DefaultValuesElements.each(function() {  // Loop through the elements you want default for
      $(this).attr("defaultvalue",$(this).val());  // Grab the value and save them into a custom attribute ("defaultvalue")
    });
  }

  function setDefaultValues() {
    DefaultValuesElements.each(function() {  // Loop through the elements you want to reset the values for
      $(this).val($(this).attr("defaultvalue"));  // Overwrite the current value with the saved default value
    });
  }

  getDefaultValues();  // Grab the values

  $("#resetvalues").click(function() {  // Belongs to the example below. Whenever the button is pressed...
    setDefaultValues();  // Reset the elements to their default values.
  });
});
```

You could put the `setDefaultValues()` code inside the `click` function, but I put it and the `getDefaultValues()` code in functions to make it more obvious.

**HTML (example)**

```
<select size='1' id="a" name='a'>
 <option value="None" selected>choices</option>
 <option value='1'>first</option>
 <option value='2'>second</option>
</select>

<input type="input" name="whatever" value="test">

<input type="button" id="resetvalues" value="Reset values">
```

This [code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/FKPXL/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but I just want to make a contribution for a similar use case like mine where I wanted to put the default value back into the select box when the user presses esc.  This also prevents the .change event from firing for the select elements.

So based on the ideas presented here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163493/jquery-datepicker-on-esc-key-event), this is another good answer:

```
var KEYCODE_ESC = 27;
// when esc is pressed while scrolling through the options
// reset value of select to default (first) value
$('select').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ESC) {
        console.log('esc key pressed on select element'); 
        $(this).val($(this).children('option:first-child').text());
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dropdown to any of your options using the value like this:

```
$('#a').selectize()[0].selectize.setValue("None", true);
```

if your default option has no value this will set it back:

```
$('#myDropdown').selectize()[0].selectize.setValue("", true);
```