# jquery datepicker on esc key event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, esc-key

I'm trying to put a date value in the input box for the date picker when the user **click on the key ESC (e.keyCode == 27) once he as open the datepicker**.

My test case:

1) Click on the input box, the date picker show up;

2) The user decide to cancel the selection by clicking on the esc key.

3) The following date should be then put as default (01/01/2011) in the input box since he has not selected any date.

**Please fork my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bizonbytes/SYwpy/45/)**

Comment: Can't replicate your problem in chrome. When I press esc it leaves normally.

Comment: Which browser do you use? It does not select anything here on Safari 5.1

Comment: He wants to know how to select a default date on Esc, not just the default functionality of a blank selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#input").val("01/01/2011");
    }
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/SYwpy/46/